# awk is not working in script running on linux

Tags: linux, awk

The String in file is

```
Wed Jan  7 03:23:03 EST 2015 Cpu(s):  3.1%us,  0.9%sy,  0.0%ni, 94.8%id,  1.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
```

by using following command

```
echo $CPU_STATS | cut -d" " -f9| awk -F'%' '{print $1}'
```

Unable to get 0.9 value which have in String
Please help

Comment: If `$CPU_STATS` contains the string `Wed Jan 7 03:23:03 EST 2015 Cpu(s): 3.1%us, 0.9%sy, 0.0%ni, 94.8%id, 1.2%wa, 0.0%hi, 0.1%si, 0.0%st`, this should work (it does for me).  What does `echo $CPU_STATS` return on its own?

Comment: It working for me @Vaibhav, [here](http://prntscr.com/5ph3fh) see the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the entire statement in `awk` as

```
$ echo $CPU_STATS | awk -F"[ %]+" '{print $10}'
0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do not want to count to 10, you can use sed:

```
echo $CPU_STATS | sed 's/.* \+\([\.0-9\]\+\)%sy.*/\1/'
```

The portion between ( and ) will be remembered and put into \1